# How to make a command button collection ms access

Tags: ms-access

Let’s say i have a 100 command buttons and images in an access form i need to deal with them as groups for example in English : Group1 includes commandbutton1 To Commandbutton10 and Image1 To Image10

```
me.group1.visible = false
```

The result would be hide buttons from 1 To 10 and hide images from 1 to 10
I need to declare the groups names and each group includes which command buttons and images then deal with them as i mentioned above how can i do that ? thanks in advance

Comment: You use separate prefix for command button name then iterate all buttons and do action with prefix. You can use left function to detect prefix.

Comment: In addition, there is the `Tag` property that you could use.

Comment: @ Harun24HR Thanks for reply , they already have a unique prefix i will try your way

Comment: @ Applecore Thanks for reply , could you give me an example of using tag the way i need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that you could look at is using the `.Tag` property of the controls. You could either just have a single piece of text and check for equality, or else you could have several pieces of text and check if a piece of text exists (which allows you to have controls being members of several groups). A basic example is:

```
Private Sub cmdVisible_Click()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ctl.Tag = "Group1" Then
            ctl.Visible = Not ctl.Visible
        End If
    Next ctl
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "frmVisible!cmdVisible_Click", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: IMHO, Tag is better than name prefix , since you can easily tag multiple objects at once, not to mention the fact that you can quickly chenge the behaviour of 1 control, without renaming it (renaming could eventually break your code)

Comment: Agreed. I normally use a naming convention for my controls as well as a descriptor, so it keeps it all separate.